# MISRA C 2012 violation of rule 9.1 even with an initialized variable

Tags: c, misra

I am trying to get rid of violation rule 9.1 from my code.

Rule 9.1: The value of an object with automatic storage duration shall not be read before it has been set

Sample code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define VAL 0xABCDEFABU

int32_t main(void);
static int32_t do_test(bool k);
static void func(uint64_t *var3, const uint64_t *var5);

int32_t 
main (void)
{
    bool b = false;

    int32_t y = do_test(b);

    return y;
}

static int32_t
do_test(bool k)
{
    uint64_t i = 0, var4[10];

    int32_t result = 0;

    for(i = 0U; i < 10U; i++) {
      var4[i] = VAL + i;
    }

    if(k == false) {
      uint64_t var2[10];
      func(var2, var4);

      if(var2[9] == var4[9]) {
        result = 1;
      }

    }

      return result;
}


static void
func(uint64_t *var3, const uint64_t *var5)
{
    int32_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var3[i] = var5[i];
    }

}
```

I am initializing var2 in the function do_test by calling another function "func" where var4 is copied to var2.

It is compiling fine and I am getting y value = 1.

Is it the violation due to parameters in func as pointers and the function do_test is not getting aware about the value assignment through pointers in func

Is there anyway to fix this issue ?

Comment: Is `var3` or `var5` initialized ? Is `var5[i]` initialized ? Obviously no, so this doesn't violate the rule.

Comment: Out of curiousity, which tool gave the warning? I think I have yet to find one which doesn't have this bug.

Comment: the function: `main()` is special in C, do not prototype it.  use a return type of `int`,

Comment: read [rule sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/code-analysis-rule-set-reference)  to learn about 'rule sets' and how to manipulate them.

Comment: Specifically, the return type of main() is nowadays explicitly excluded from the MISRA-C directive that requires that types like those of stdint.h should be used.

Comment: Detail: "I am initializing var2 in ... function "func" ".  C describes this as _assigning_ the elements of `var2`.  To _initialize_ `var2`, use `uint64_t  var4[10]  = { something };`  Anything after that is _assignment_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common tool bug in many static analysers. Your static analyser can apparently not understand that the function `func` initializes all the items of `var2`, and therefore you get the false positive on the line `var2[9] == var4[9]`.

On many static analysers, code such as `int my_array[10]; initialize(my_array);` gives frustrating false positives. "You try to initialize the array before it has been initialized!!!" Oh really... thank you, most helpful static analyser.

Your code is fine. File a bug report with your tool vendor.

Comment: @LundinI got the same violation for a switch statement:     switch (val) {
      case 0:
          result = 1;
          break;
      case 1:
          result = 2;
          break;
 
      case 2:
          if(temp == 1) {
            result = 2;
          }
 
          int32_t a = 10;
          a += 5;
          result = a;
          break;
 
      case 3:
          result = 4;
          break;
      
      default:
          result = 0;
          break;
    } . when I introduced curly braces for case 2 the issue got resolved. What could be the reason ?

Comment: @Salim Tool bugs.

Comment: '      I am facing another scenario where rule 9.1 getting violated. 

I want to read an auto variable(having garbage value while declaring) before initialization and to assign null  if it is not null. If it is null, then with different value.

Sample code:
{
       int8_t reg_num;
       uint64_t var1[NUM]; 

       
       for (reg_num = 0; reg_num < NUM; reg_num++) {
           if (var1[reg_num] != VAR_NULL) {
                var1 [reg_num] = VAR_NULL;
           } else {  
                var1[reg_num] = func1();
           }
       }
    }

Comment: @Salim Reading an automatic storage duration variable (which does not have its address taken) before initialization is always undefined behavior. Thus your code has a bug: the loop doesn't make sense. Simply initialize `uint64_t var1[NUM] = { 0 };`. Bug fixed. As a bonus your code turned much faster and more readable.